# Starting virtual machine on gcp compute engine with web-uri

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, api-key

I set up a VM on CE. I want to start and shutdown this VM with the API using the instances().stop and instances().start method with a HTTP request.

Using the API explorer (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/start) and putting in project-name, zone and instance-name everything works fine and i can start and stop the VM. I am forwarded to the google login -> i authorize --> it works.

However, when i try to do this via the provided html in my browser: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{my_projekt}/zones/{my_zone}/instances/{my_instance}/start", it doesn't work. Error: Not found. I figured that some kind of autorization is missing so i also tried to add ?key={my_key}.

In the documentation i find:
  Requires one of the following OAuth scopes:
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

But i don't know how to set this up. Someone can help me with that? Is it even possible what i am trying to do?

In a next step i would like to allow others to start and stop this vm by giving them IAM roles. Can they use http post requests as well?

I am pretty new in working with GCP and the autorization process gives me a headache ...

Thanks in advance.
Greetings,
Oli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you have 3 ways to achieve this, they are well documented in [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance), I will list them from the easiest to the harder:

A.- Google Cloud Console.

B.- Google Cloud SDK CLI tool "gcloud".

C.- Google Cloud HTTP API calls.

The permission the account will need to perform the Stop/start of the instance will be:

```
compute.instances.stop
compute.instances.start
```

to reset:

```
compute.instances.reset
```

A role that has these permission is "compute.instanceAdmin", however you can always create a customer role with the desired permissions.

---

A.- Google Cloud Console

Is the most user friendly way to do it, since it uses a GUI. Go to the Cloud Console, On your [Compute Engine Instances](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances). If you don't see your instances on the list, be sure you have selected the proper project.

Click on the instances you want to stop/start and click on the buttons above according to what you want to do.

---

B.- Google Cloud SDK CLI tool "gcloud"

[Install](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install) the CLI tool "gcloud", [authenticate](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login) into it using:

```
gcloud auth login [ACCOUNT]
```

Then you will be able to use the commands to [Stop](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/stop)/[Start](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/start)/[Reset](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/reset) the instances

```
gcloud compute instances stop example-instance-1 example-instance-2

gcloud compute instances start example-instance

gcloud compute instances reset example-instance
```

---

C.- Google Cloud HTTP API calls

This is the method you are currently trying to use, you'll have to make an HTTP request to the Google Cloud API: [Start](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/start) , [Stop](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/stop) , [Reset](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/reset).

You will need to add your "access token" into the "authentication" field on the header on the request. using "Authorization: bearer here-your-long-token". More information about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#apiauth).

How to get the "access token" may vary depending on the language you are using, here's an example in javascript:

```
var {google} = require("googleapis");

// Load the service account key JSON file.
var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

// Define the required scopes.
var scopes = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute"
];

// Authenticate a JWT client with the service account.
var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  serviceAccount.client_email,
  null,
  serviceAccount.private_key,
  scopes
);

// Use the JWT client to generate an access token.
jwtClient.authorize(function(error, tokens) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Error making request to generate access token:", error);
  } else if (tokens.access_token === null) {
    console.log("Provided service account does not have permission to generate access tokens");
  } else {
    var accessToken = tokens.access_token;
    // here you have the token, you can use it on your API request.
  }
});
```